# For mySQL 5.7 is it possible to convert an _arbitrary_ SQL query into JSON without knowing the query's shape a priori?

Tags: mysql, json

I've inherited a project that stores SQL queries inside mySQL tables (long story). I want to run those queries *from a stored procedure* and automatically convert the resultset to a JSON array of objects with keys equal to the selected columns.

I am trying to avoid a round-trip to the database to run these queries; hence me trying to do this in a stored procedure vs say python or php.

I don't see any way of doing this after searching here and the documentation pretty hard. I was hoping to find some functionality like "row to json" which takes an arbitrary row and returns it as json based on the columns returned. Is that possible?

Comment: You sure this is the direction you want to develop the project? In my experience, most of the "complex" MySQL features are best avoided for different reasons... and on the way to re-factor away legacy code, adding another layer seems like the wrong direction?

Comment: If you know the columns... [json_object()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object)  If you don't know the columns, you need to write code that can infer or derive the columns, then write code to write the sql. There is no short hand that allows this without specifying the keys.  Alternatively, convert to json in an separate layer of your application, and don't try to do it in SQL.

Comment: I'm stuck dealing with this setup for the time being. It's a legacy work thing and it's not on the table to change it. They do need arbitrary data associated with records where that data comes from arbitrary evaluated SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of trial and error, I was able to figure it out myself. Enjoy!

```sql
------------------------------------------------------------
-- columns_of_table
--
-- Sets @columns to JSON array of column names.
-- Works with temporary tables.
-- Cannot be a function since it uses dynamic SQL.
------------------------------------------------------------

DELIMITER ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS columns_of_table;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE columns_of_table(table_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN 
  SET @columns = '[]';  
  SET @query = CONCAT(
    'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ', table_name, 
    ' WHERE @columns := JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@columns, "$", Field)'
  );
  PREPARE show_cols FROM @query;
  EXECUTE show_cols; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE show_cols; 
END;
$$

------------------------------------------------------------
-- query_to_json
-- 
-- Runs given query and converts resultset to JSON array.
--
-- Note: memory engine doesn't work if there are TEXT or
-- BLOB fields in the resultset as temporary tables cannot 
-- contain TEXT or BLOB fields for some mystical reason.
--
-- Cannot be a function since it uses dynamic SQL.
--
-- Sets @json_results.
------------------------------------------------------------

DELIMITER ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS query_to_json;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE query_to_json(query TEXT, use_memory_engine BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE col VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE object_params TEXT DEFAULT '';

  -- Wrap the query such that the results are stored in a temporary table.
  
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_results;
  SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_results ',
    IF(use_memory_engine, ' ENGINE=memory ', ''),
    query);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  -- Find the columns of the temporary table.

  CALL columns_of_table('temp_results');

  -- Convert from @columns of '["x", "y"]' to object_params of '"x", x, "y", y'
  -- which are interpolated into SQL that calls JSON_OBJECT.

  WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(@columns) DO
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@columns, CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) INTO col;
    SET object_params = CONCAT(object_params, col, ',', REPLACE(col, '"', ''), ',');
    SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
  END WHILE;
  SET object_params = TRIM("," FROM object_params);

  -- Run dynamic query that fetches result rows as JSON objects and concatenates
  -- them into a proper JSON array.  If you have access to JSON_ARRAYAGG, consider
  -- updating this.
  
  SET @query = CONCAT(
    'SELECT CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(', object_params, ')), "]") ', 
    'FROM temp_results '
    'INTO @json_results'
  );
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```